# Detect 0 or nil values of NSNumber in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, null

There are many accepted answers here on SO and elsewhere about how to detect a nil value but many conflict and none seem to be working for me.  I have an NSNumber that logs to the console as 0.  I want to screen it out as follows:

```
NSNumber *itemid = item.iid;

//pseudocode
if (itemid is not 0 or nil or null or empty or missing, i.e. is something like 22222) {
//there is an item id.
}
```

I have tried many variations of the following but the logic is not working:

```
NSLog(@"itemid is:%@",itemid); //logs as 0
    if (![itemid isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] && itemid!=nil &&![itemid intValue]==0) {
             NSLog(@"there is an itemid");
    }
```

Can anyone recommend a foolproof way to do this?  Cheers.

Comment: What's wrong with only testing `([itemid intValue] != 0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `itemid` can could be `NSNull`, then this line of code is broken:

```
NSNumber *itemid = item.iid;
```

It is never appropriate to assign an `NSNull` value to an `NSNumber` variable. So first, you need to take care of that.

```
// This will also happen to take care of the nil case.
if (! [item.iid isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) { 
    return; // Get us out of here. Someone did a bad thing. We should really NSAssert here.
}
```

If your `item` object says it returns an `NSNumber` for `iid`, then it needs to get rid of the `NSNull` value internally and always return an `NSNumber` or nil. That's its job; callers shouldn't have to fix up cases where `item` lies.

OK, now let's assume that we know that `itemid` really is an `NSNumber` and no one is doing anything crazy like putting an `NSNull` in it. Then it's either a number or a `nil`. (If you did the previous check we know it isn't `nil`, too.) Either way, `intValue` will be 0, so:

```
if ([item.idd intValue] == 0) {
    return; // Nothing to see here.
}
```

The key to understand is that when you send a message to `nil`, it always return "a zero-like value." 0, 0.0, false, or nil, depending on whether it's some kind of number, a boolean, or an object. If a struct is returned, it'll be that struct filled with zeros. Whatever is most like "lots of zeros" is what you'll get back. Relying on that fact is very normal in ObjC and fine practice.